# Let $G$ be a group of order $2n$. Show that $f$ can not be surjective.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $2n$, $f:G\rightarrow G$ be a mapping such that $f(x)=x^2$.

> Show that $f$ can not be surjective.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I have edited your question according to $\LaTeX$ notation. You will note that it looks much better. Please try and use $\LaTeX$ when writing your next posts - just look at the source of other posts for examples. Also, please try and explain where the problem comes from, what is your knowledge of the subject, and what have you tried so far - people will be more willing to help - and don't be put off by the negative votes. Enjoy MSE!

Comment: Show what you have done so far, unless we can't help you

Comment: if G is commutative then applying 1st iso theorem n=2n. This case is obvious. If G is nonabelian i have no idea how to proceed....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|G|$ is even, one knows that $G$ contains a subgroup $H=\{e,g\}$ consisting of exactly 2 elements. Since $g^2=e$ we must have
$$
f(g)=f(e)=e
$$
so that $f$ is not injective. But then $f$ is not surjective either, because $G$ is finite.

---

**ADDED:** 4 answers at the same time!

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to show that the mapping cannot be injective.

We show that there are at least two solutions of $x^2=e$, where $e$ is the identity.

Pair $a$ and $b$, where $a\ne b$, if $ab=e$. Note that for any $a$ there is at most one $b$ paired with $a$, and that if $b$ is paired with $a$, then $a$ is paired with $b$.

Thus an even number of elements of $G$ belong to couples. Since $G$ has even order, it follows that an even number of elements $x$ of $G$ are "single." But $e$ is "single," so there is at least one other "single," meaning at least one additional solution of $x^2=e$. It follows that the function $x^2$ is not injective.

Comment: +1 IMHO this is not the time to apply Cauchy. Nothing wrong with the other answers, but ...

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be an element of order $2$ then $x^2=e$, since this map is not one to one from $G$ to $G$, it can not be onto.

**Note:** Such a $x$ exists by Cauchy theorems.

**Added:** You may want to learn more strong result;

Let $G$ is a finite group of order $n$ and $f:G\mapsto G$ be function with $f(x)=x^k$ then $f$ is a bijection if and only if  $gcd(k,n)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Cauchy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29), it is possible to show that $f$ maps two elements of $G$ to the identity.  Now apply the fact that, since $|G|$ is finite, $f$ is surjective $\iff$ $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a *silly* (repeat, **silly**) extra answer, proving directly that $f$ cannot be surjective.

Consider an element $x \in G$ of the maximum possible order of the form $2^{k}$. By Cauchy's theorem, $x \ne e$, that is, $k \ge 1$. Then $x$ cannot be in the image of $f$, because if there is $y \in G$ such that $x = f(y) = y^2$, then $y$ has order $2^{k+1}$, because $y^{2^{k+1}} = x^{2^{k}} = e$, while $y^{2^{k}} = x^{2^{k-1}} \ne e$. (Here we have used $x \ne e$, that is, $k \ge 1$.)